# laravel left join for same table with different date range

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Hello I am new on Laravel, the following SQL is verified working well as I expected,
However, I can't make it work in Laravel......

Might I have your help

```
select *, SUM(CASE WHEN `parts_trans`.`in_out` = "In" THEN `parts_trans`.`qty` else -1 * `parts_trans`.`qty` END)as amount 
from `parts_trans` 
left join ( 
        SELECT `id`, SUM(CASE WHEN `in_out` = "Out" THEN qty END)as amount_out , SUM(CASE WHEN `in_out` = "In" THEN qty END)as amount_in 
        FROM `parts_trans` 
        WHERE `updated_at` between '2013-03-26' and '2021-04-26' 
        group by `part_info_id` 
) as p2 
on `parts_trans`.`id` = `p2`.`id` 
group by `parts_trans`.`part_info_id`
```

I had try

```
$from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-90 days'));
$to = date('Y-m-d');

$grid->model()
    ->selectRaw('*, SUM(CASE WHEN `in_out` = "Out" THEN `qty` END)as amount_out , SUM(CASE WHEN `in_out` = "In" THEN `qty` END) as amount_in')
    ->whereBetween('updated_at', [$from, $to])
    ->groupBy('part_info_id')
    ->leftJoin('parts_trans AS p2', function ($join) {
        $join->on('p2.id', '=', 'parts_trans.id')
        ->select('p2.id', 'SUM(CASE WHEN `p2.in_out` = "In" THEN `p2.qty` else -1 * `p2.qty` END)as amount')
        ->groupBy('p2.part_info_id');
    });
```

it turn out

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'in_out' in field list is ambiguous
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (
    select *, SUM(CASE WHEN `in_out` = "Out" THEN `qty` END)as amount_out , SUM(CASE WHEN `in_out` = "In" THEN `qty` END) as amount_in 
    from `parts_trans` 
    left join `parts_trans` as `p2` 
    on `p2`.`id` = `parts_trans`.`id`
        where `updated_at` between 2021-01-13 and 2021-04-13 group by `part_info_id`) as `aggregate_table`)
```

Comment: according to error code, I think you need to alter your query a bit , add a alias for first `parts_trans` and add that on `in_out`, something like `p1.in_out`.

Comment: if column with same name in both table doesn't specify belong to which table, will cause error.

Comment: I recommend you to leave any logic to PHP/Laravel, do not try to write hard SQL queries because no one will understand it, the idea is to use Eloquent as if you were writing good code, so anyone can understand what is is being done with the query, but your query is huge and massive, I do not recommend to use it like that.

Comment: don't use `select *` or  `selectRaw('*`  be specific, and use aliases when you have joined tables/subqueries, it's a simple fix